# initial data in django model form

Tags: django, django-forms

I use the following code to call the register_guest_order view but it doesn't prefill the guest data on the order form.

Model/Form:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    guest = models.ForeignKey('hotel.Guest', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    item = models.ForeignKey('hotel.Item', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    is_paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    paid_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('guest', 'item', 'amount')
```

View:

```
@login_required
def register_guest_order(request, *args, **kwargs):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterGuestForm(request.POST, initial={'guest': kwargs['go']})
        if form.is_valid():
            guest = form.save(commit=False)
            guest.save()
            #post.published_date = timezone.now()
            return redirect('guests')
    else:
            return redirect ('new_order')
    context = {'form': form}
    return redirect('guests')
```

url:

```
url(r'^guest/orders/(?P<go>\d+)$', views.register_guest_order, name='new_guest_order'),
```

template:

```
<a href="{% url 'new_guest_order' go=Guest.pk %}">
```

Comment: Can you fix your indentation? It's not clear if that `else` is in the right place.

Comment: it seems to be correctly displayed on my desktop although I have to admit it looked weird on mobile.. but wouldn't know what to do about it..